# How to implement alternating colours animation on iOS

Tags: ios, animation

I've designed a custom indicator View for my application which consists of a row of 10 circles. The indicator indicates the progress of a task and the closer the task is to finishing, the more circles are filled. I would like to add two very basic animations to this indicator and, because this is my first iOS application, I'm not sure what the best way to implement them is.

**Animation 1**: While the task progress information is being fetched from the server, I want each dot to change color (from black to blue) in succession.

**Animation 2**: Let's say I get that a task is 80% complete from the server, I want to change the color of the first 8 dots from black to green with a decreasing delay.

My question is, is it okay to implement these animations in `drawRect:` or is there a more standard way of implementing something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `drawRect:` at all for this UI. I would create the circles using a `UIShapeLayer` with a circle for its `path`, and do the animations with 
`animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion`; this method allows you to add animations for the individual circles (using `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:`) with whatever delay and relative duration you need between the keyframes.